# Laravel Fortify (Jetstream) Login Without Reload Using Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-fortify

I'm using Laravel Jetstream with Livewire for my authentication. I've used Livewire 3 Navigation to create links without reloading and logout without reloading. But I'm still stuck in one thing. I want to make the login itself without reloading. I tried to create my own LoginResponse and then override the original LoginResponse. But it doesn't work. When I click the "Login" button, it reloads and shows a blank page.

This is my LoginResponse, which is located in App\Livewire\LoginResponse.php:

```
namespace App\Livewire;

use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as ContractsLoginResponse;
use Livewire\Component;

class LoginResponse extends Component implements ContractsLoginResponse
{
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false])
            : $this->redirect('/', navigate: true);
    }
}
```

And then this is my code in App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->app->singleton(
        \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse::class,
        \App\Livewire\LoginResponse::class,
    );
}
```

What did I do wrong, and how can I implement the login process without reloading in Laravel Fortify (Jetstream) Livewire?

Comment: I don't know if this is actually possible, as it's not documented anywhere in the Livewire documentation. However, are you sure the form is wired up correctly to livewire? Livewire shouldn't refresh the entire page if you're handling your form in this fashion: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/forms

It looks as though your implkementation is closer to a traditional form handler, rather than the livewire-esque approach.

Comment: @Oddman I don't do the form like from your link. Because Fortify handle the login process, I don't need to create Login Component. I guess that's also part of the problem.

Comment: Yup, I'd say so. Jetstream with Fortify manages this different, as it's wired up directly to livewire

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that Livewire only updates page elements within the scope of each Livewire component. I assume you have a login form which is a Livewire component. What you can do to update the rest of page elements, once the user logs in, is emitting a Livewire event upon successful authentication. The event can be listened to by another Livewire component and proper action can take place.

In your login function, after successful login:

```
public function login()
{
    // authentication logic

    // if authentication is successful
    $this->dispatch('logged-in', username: $user->name); 
}
```

And in another component which is responsible for some part of the page, you can list to the *logged-in* event:

```
#[On('logged-in')] 
public function updateNavBar($username)
{
    // set username value to the relevant variable and show it
}
```

You can read [the docs on events](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events#dispatching-events) and get a better insight on how to achieve this functionality.